# Different twig template for user profiles of different role

Tags: 8, theming, users

I would like to theme user profile pages differently based on the role but I can't figure it out how to do so.

I will need when someone is viewing an administrator profile this twig file to be loaded:
user--administrator.html.twig

and when is viewing an editor profile this:
user--editor.html.twig

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can done by adding a hook theme suggestion based on roles in your `YOUR_THEME.theme` file

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_user_alter().
 */
function YOUR_THEME_theme_suggestions_user_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  foreach ($variables['elements']['#user']->getRoles() as $role) {
    $suggestions[] = 'user__' . $role;
  }
}
```

Then you can use templates like `user--administrator.html.twig`, `user--editor.html.twig`

Comment: What this does is to change the template based on the role of the user. So if an editor sees the profile of an administrator they will see the user--editor.html.twig

Comment: Then you should loop the roles of the currently loaded user in the page `$variables['elements']['#user']->getRoles()`. I have updated the code.